# Basic Video Editing - Ubuntu Linux

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I will have some home movies converted to video.  I will need to import and edit these in pretty basic ways - copy entire sections to another location and give it it's own file name, etc.

I have no need to make my own graphics, games, or anything like that.

If there are "clean up" capabilities to fix minor problems in the video, I might use them if they are easy to use.

I hear most other Ubuntu Linux video editors crash more than a blind pilot, but this one is good.

What is not clear from anything I can find is: "Does this program do simple things like the above, or not?"  If not, what is my best choice?

Comment: I think blender will be able to do those things without much trouble. However the video editor is definitely not the strongest part of blender, and wasn't really designed with general video editing in mind (still works fine though). [I've run the gamut of opensource video editors too](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14656/1279), and perhaps my favorite non-blender editor at the moment is [shotcut](http://shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Blender does do basic editing.

Keep in mind that Blender was designed as a 3D application so the video editor is a bit of an addon. It works fine and is quite usable, but the workflow isn't as optimized as a normal video editor. The more complex your edit, the more hacky things become. Just keep this in mind.

Moving the locations of files and renaming should be taken care of by your operating system. Doing using Blender would just be over complicating it.

Comment: What I need to do is to slice up video files into new separate ones, move those and rename them.  It's not just move and name.

Comment: Essentially you want to cut up your videos and then render them out to different names. That is definitely possible with Blender.